# How would you achieve multiple drag and drop with ember

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, drag-and-drop

I've seen different examples of single object drag and drop like referenced in this question [Ember.js + HTML5 drag and drop shopping cart demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762484/ember-js-html5-drag-and-drop-shopping-cart-demo)

But since the drag event is on the view object, I don't se how I would achieve multiple view selection drag and drop (aka like in an email client or in evernote for instance).

Any jsbin is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of using drag and drop using `ember` along with `jquery-ui` . Although it is not necessary to split the draggable components into separate views, they have been split just to demonstrate the multiple view selection mentioned by the op.

So combine the following code with the example found in this thread

[How do I drag multiple elements at once with JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677993/how-do-i-drag-multiple-elements-with-javascript-or-jquery)

(look at the comments http://jsfiddle.net/zVZFq/358/)

### http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sasasuka/1/edit

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each post in model}}
    {{#with post}}
    <div class="placeholder">
      {{render "post" post}}
      </div>
      {{/with}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
  <div class="post" {{bind-attr id="id"}}>
    {{name}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    
    return allPosts;
  }
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames:["post-container"]
});

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});

App.PostView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"post",
  classNameBindings: ['selected'],
  selected:Ember.computed.alias("context.selected"),
   didInsertElement:function(){
     
    this.$(".post").draggable({ revert: "invalid", snap: ".post-container",snapMode:"inner" });
    
    var self = this;
        
        /*jquery ui create the draggable component*/
        this.$(".post").draggable({ revert: "invalid", snap: ".post-container",snapMode:"inner" });
        
        /*create the droppable component*/
        this.$().droppable({
          drop:function(event,ui){
            
            var draggedPostId = parseInt(ui.draggable.attr("id"),10);
            var draggedPost = self.get("parentView").get("controller").findBy("id",draggedPostId);
            var draggedOrder = draggedPost.get("order");
            
            var droppedPost = self.get("controller").get("model");
            var droppedOrder = droppedPost.get("order");
            
            draggedPost.set("order",droppedOrder);
            droppedPost.set("order",draggedOrder);
            
            allPosts = allPosts.sortBy("order");
            self.get("parentView").get("controller").set("model",allPosts);
          }
        });
   },
  
    click:function(){
      this.toggleProperty("controller.selected");
    }
  
});


App.Post = Ember.Object.extend({
  id:null,
  name:null,
  order:null
});

/*this would come from a server or web storage*/
var allPosts = [];
     allPosts.pushObject(App.Post.create({id:1,name:"post1",order:1}));
     allPosts.pushObject(App.Post.create({id:2,name:"post2",order:2}));
allPosts.pushObject(App.Post.create({id:3,name:"post3",order:3}));
allPosts.pushObject(App.Post.create({id:4,name:"post4",order:4}));
allPosts.pushObject(App.Post.create({id:5,name:"post5",order:5}));
```

Comment: So there is no way to make it work without jquery-ui, just with Ember view events?

Comment: @borisrorsvort as far as i know there is no out of the box functionality related to drag'n'drop in ember, and to be honest it would be weird to have one. Here i tried to demonstrate a simple example along with suggestions for implementing your requirement, using views. Also you can certainly not use jquery-ui and use the nice implementation you mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762484/ember-js-html5-drag-and-drop-shopping-cart-demo , just remove the jquery-ui part and add the mixins mentioned in the thread.

Comment: Thanks but in the related question there no way to drag multiple at once. So no I can't just use the other example without jquery ui

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jqueryUI for this. Add the file below into your app and then you can extend the custom jquery views!

https://gist.github.com/jamesmgg/9191149

Comment: Jaime, this seems like a interesting option. Could you give an example on how to implement drag and drop in Ember with it?